Angular 18 custom element without generating a component first
Given the following example in main.ts:
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { createCustomElement } from '@angular/elements';
import { CardComponent } from './app/shared/components/card/card.component';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)
.then((app) => {
    const cardComponent = createCustomElement(CardComponent, {injector: app.injector});
    customElements.define('crm-component', cardComponent);
})
.catch((err) => console.error(err));

we see that we have a properly bootstrapped application with a custom element called crm-component that is created from a shared component called CardComponent already found within the application. This is redundant.
Is it possible to achieve the same outcome upon bootstrapping the application without having previously created the CardComponent and doing all the code inside of the callback?
So far the answer I have found on my own is "no" or "not easily". You need to be able to mimic the @Component decorator. I have not found a simple way to do so. I'm curious to see if anyone else has attempted this.

what do you want to skip? creating angular component CardComponent?

It's not recommanded to create component "on the fly", as you'll have to use the JIT compiler, which inflates the bundle size and is known to produce worse perfs.
